# respond_with/to rendering wrong view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, respond-with

I'm trying to understand why respond_with/to is rendering the wrong view...

#### controller

```
respond_to :html, :js

def get_numbers
  Rails.logger.info request.format
  @numbers = Number.all
  respond_with @numbers
end
```

when making an ajax request, the rails log shows the format is `JS`, and the request format is `text/javascript`, but it renders the html view.

#### log

```
Started GET "/numbers/get_numbers?_=1333564838110" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-04 11:40:38 -0700
Processing by NumbersController#get_numbers as JS
  ...
text/javascript
  Rendered numbers/get_numbers.html.haml within layouts/application (106.4ms)
```

and i have both a `get_numbers.html.haml` & `get_numbers.js.coffee` view in `views/numbers`

i could render the correct view by doing:

```
respond_with @numbers do |format|
  format.js {}
end
```

but shouldn't it be rendering the js view with just `respond_with @numbers`

Comment: When all you want is the js, why are you using html as well. The syntax in the respond_to block doesn't look much readable to me as well. Change it to meet your specific needs.

Comment: im using both html and js.  and not sure what you mean with the respond_to block. i removed the :only option from the example since it isn't pertinent to the problem.  this is a contrived example btw.

Comment: Can you post the relevant routes, as well as your Gemfile.lock?

Comment: In your controller, you are telling it to respond with either html or js, and that will be determined when you ask for it in the Ajax request. Check your AJAX request for the format asked, and do some debugging there. Also check the relevant routes as @mosch said.

Comment: the ajax request format is correct (text/javascript), and the route is setup properly (GET numbers#get_numbers). updated the post to show the GET request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the response to be JavaScript when no format is explicitly specified (meaning no `.html` or `.js` in the URL), you can set the default format parameter in your route:

```
match '/numbers/get_numbers(.:format)' => 'numbers#get_numbers', :defaults => { :format => :js }
```

You might also get your desired results by switching the order of the formats in your call to `respond_to`, since it seems to default to the first one, but I haven't tested that.

Comment: that was it!  though instead of setting the default format on my route i am setting it on the url, but that was the problem nonetheless...

Comment: also... why couldn't rails match the appropriate response with just request.format?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really know. It does seem strange that the logs indicate that it's responding as `JS` but rendering the HTML template. If you can get a minimal reproducible case, [open a bug against Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues).